# Can a child class name also appear in an xml output

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I have the following sample C# code :

```
public class child {
    public string mem {get; set;}
}
public class parent {
    public child myChild { get; set;}
    public string parmem {get; set;}
    public parent() {
        parmem = "I AM PARENT" ;
        myChild = new child();
        myChild.mem = "I AM  CHILD";
    }
}

class prog {
     static void Main() {
         parent par = new parent() ;
         TextWriter write = new StreamWriter("MyClass.xml");

         XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(par.GetType());
         ser.Serialize(write, par);
         write.Close();
    }
}
```

Now, I am trying to serialize an object of class 'parent' via XmlSerializer.
My output looks something as :

```
<parent xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <myChild>
        <mem>I AM CHILD</mem>
    </myChild>
    <parmem>I AM PARENT</parmem>
</parent>
```

What I want is something as follows :

```
<parent xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    **<child >
        <myChild>
            <mem>I AM CHILD</mem>
        </myChild>
    </child>**
    <parmem>I AM PARENT</parmem>
</parent>
```

Thus I want the name of the child class to also appear in the xml output.
Please tell me if it is possible to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `<myChild>` element will be added inside your `<child>` element after `XmlSerialization` then you need to declare `List<child>` property instead of single `child` property inside `parent` class.

e.g.

```
public class parent {
    [XmlArray("child")]
    [XmlArrayItem("mychild")]
    public List<child> myChilds { get; set;}
    public string parmem {get; set;}
    public parent() {
        parmem = "I AM PARENT" ;
        myChilds = new List<child>();
        myChilds.Add(new child() {mem  = "I AM  CHILD"} ); 
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parent xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <child>
    <mychild>
      <mem>I AM  CHILD</mem>
    </mychild>
  </child>
  <parmem>I AM PARENT</parmem>
</parent>
```

Comment: But what if I really did not want to use alist object there. I mean, I may want parent to have a single child only

Comment: I am afraid that you cannot achieve what you want without List. If you want to only one child then add only one element in List.